C++ programs fail with ASAN (AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL)
I have been using ASAN in C++ for a long time, and now I just link with ASAN and get DEADLYSIGNAL executing the resulting program. For example:
p.cpp:
 int main() { return 0; }
I compile it:
$ c++ -o p p.cpp -fsanitize=address -fsanitize=undefined
I execute it:
$ ./p
AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

This began to happen in some machines. In the machines where compiling with ASAN works, also works an executable compiled with ASAN in a machine where ASAN fails, so it does not seem to be a problem within the executable itself.
If I use a single sanitization, either sanitize=undefined or sanitize=address, it also works, but the combination of both fails. Of course, with no sanitization at all, works fine as well.
My setup is:
$ c++ --version
c++ (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Under Ubuntu 22.04.4.
gdb does not allow debugging on programs compiled with ASAN, but here's its output for what is worth:
$ gdb p
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 12.1-0ubuntu1~22.04) 12.1
Copyright (C) 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.

For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from p...
(gdb) run
Starting program: /tmp/p 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
==432014==LeakSanitizer has encountered a fatal error.
==432014==HINT: For debugging, try setting environment variable LSAN_OPTIONS=verbosity=1:log_threads=1
==432014==HINT: LeakSanitizer does not work under ptrace (strace, gdb, etc)
[Inferior 1 (process 432014) exited with code 01]
(gdb) bt
No stack.
(gdb) 

Later notes:

this bug is perfectly reproducible by installing a fresh Ubuntu 22.04 and installing g++.
in some machines it takes a few tries before reproducing it.
at this point, I have not a single Ubuntu 22.04 machine where this bug does not reproduce.


Does the debugger show anything?

Nothing, just that.

Can you show the gdb log? What backtrace does it show when you type bt?

Is this compiled with gcc or you are using clang? Which exact version of compiler it is?

For sanitizers to give you a useful backtrace, you should compile your code with debug symbols, e.g. supply -g as the compiler option. Otherwise the sanitizers might detect errors, but can't give you any information where in the code the error occurs.

I use ASAN and UBSAN together all the time, and I haven't seen this issue (yet... I probably just jinxed myself).

I just tried your simple example in a fresh Ubuntu 22.04.4 Docker container, and the program successfully executes without any issues. Do you by any chance have LD_PRELOAD or LD_LIBRARY_PATH set so that the program loads other libraries that may themselves fail with ASAN/UBSAN?

11.4.0 seems a bit old. I'm on g++ (Ubuntu 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 12.3.0 and it doesn't have the problem your version has. Does upgrading help?

I will add the gdb output in the post

@MarekR: gcc, the compiler version is in the post itself

@chris_se no, no other LD_* variables in the environment. I started seeing this issue on some machines, but in others with the exact same setup woudn't reproduce it. At some point it began to happen on almost all of them, I don't know if it has to do with some update.

@TedLyngmo I didn't try to upgrade the compiler yet. They are machines used for active development, so I don't want to alter the environment too much.

@HolyBlackCat I added the gdb output to the post, but gdb can't debut ASAN-compiled programas as far as I know.

It might be worth comparing the output from ldd p on good and bad machines, and if it's still not obvious you can compare checksums for all the linked libraries (or gather the exact apt versions for each of them)

Far fetched perhaps but does adding -ggdb make a difference?

@Leandro what happens if you add a #include <unistd.h> and write(1, "Hello World\n", 13); to main? (Not using cout here on purpose.) Does that get executed? Or does it already fail before it can print something? (Again, that said: same compiler, same Ubuntu version, works for me, so there's probably something going on with your environment. Does sudo debsums -as indicate that some files were changed on your system? Install the debsums package if it isn't already present.)

Check environment variables if there are no some changes in sanitizer settings. This should just work. This must be something wrong with your environment. Do you use multiple compilers on this system? Maybe there is some nasty interaction between those compilers, by using wrong version of header files or some dynamic library from wrong version.

@chris_se adding the hello world doesn't change anything, when it fails no print is made. dbsums output is alright.

Do you have multiple sanitizer versions installed? Is it picking the correct versions?

@MarekR  no environment variables related to the sanitizer are present. I have different machines, installed in their home offices by different people, all using same Ubuntu version with the default compiler, and it fails equally. They are not cloned machines, but installed at different points in time, by different people, with different setups, except the compiler and operating system versions.

@TedLyngmo no, same situation

Ok so you have libasan6 installed and ldd p shows libasan.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.6 (or something to that effect)

@TedLyngmo I did not install sanitizer versions other than the defaults, but for what is worth they are libasan.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.6 and libubsan.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libubsan.so.1

@Leandro as I said: I've tried this in a fresh Docker container: docker run -it ubuntu:22.04 /bin/bash -l, then apt update, apt dist-upgrade, apt install build-essential, apt install $myfavorite-cli-editor and then create the trivial C++ example file, compile it with the same options that you have mentioned, and then run it. That works for me. So your systems and a simple Docker container appear to be different in some manner. As others have mentioned, check with ldd to see if the same libraries are used, and compare them between systems via sha256sum.

(Also, maybe the sanitizer libraries are the same in your case, but maybe other libraries aren't for some reason, e.g. the C++ standard library, or the GNU C library. If those then trigger ASAN/UBSAN during startup, that could be your culprit. And you could also check to see if your dynamic loader is the same, i.e. check /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2.)

@chris_se I discovered that in the machines that work it takes a couple of tries but they fail as well. I tried in a completely different machine from a friend (also Ubuntu 22.04), I installed g++ fresh from scratch and I get the exact same result. How come nobody else can reproduce it?

@Leandro I've just retried it in my Docker container (see above for how I created it), and ran the following in bash: (n=0; while true ; do n=$((n+1)) ; i=$((n%1024)) ; if [ $i -eq 0 ] ; then echo $n ; fi ; ./p || exit 1 ; done)   That will try to run your program in a constant loop until it fails, and every 1024 executions it will print the number of iterations. I've run this for > 100k executions now in my Docker container (took a while), and it never failed. My guess would be that you install another software on your system that causes this. What, I don't know.

@Leandro Interesting: I just tried that with an Ubuntu 22.04.4 VM, and there I could reproduce it sporadically, but not within a Docker container running on another distribution. Maybe it's related to the kernel. Or it could be related to other software that's installed in a default installation, but not a minimalistic Docker container. I don't have the time to investigate right now, but I'll take a closer look in the next couple of days.

@chris_se I just installed a fresh Ubuntu 22.04 in a completely unrelated machine; after that, I installed g++ and proceeded to reproduce the bug at first try. Now I must say that during a long time I haven't had this problem at all, it only began to appear like a month ago in one machine and then spread to other machines with time. Now I have not a single machine where this bug does not reproduce. Thank you very much for your interest in this bug. I cannot understand why nobody else seems to reproduce it.

EDIT: This is the same issue as:
Possible Bug in GCC Sanitizers?
See that thread for a more detailed explanation about the root cause.
Original Response
I just did some tests, and found that this is somehow related to ASLR (address space layout randomization). If you disable it (echo 0 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space) it will not crash. (At least it didn't crash for >20k tries.) This is also the reason why it doesn't crash every time, because it apparently depends on where in the address space the libraries get loaded.
As a workaround you can disable ASLR on your development systems, but I would not recommend that in production, as ASLR is a useful security feature.
This also gives a hint as to why it doesn't occur in an Ubuntu Docker container on another distro, because the kernel actually handles parts of ASLR, and a Docker container still runs on the kernel of the other distribution.
My guess would be that Ubuntu applies some kernel patch that affects ASLR in a different way than other distributions, which is why this only occurs with Ubuntu VMs / direct installations, but not in e.g. Docker. It doesn't mean that the patch Ubuntu uses is necessarily faulty, it could still be that there's a bug in glibc and/or libasan that is only triggered by the conditions created by the Ubuntu kernel. (Or they indeed introduced a bug in the kernel.)
I'll have a closer look at this issue on the weekend, but I hope this workaround helps you out in the mean time.
(See also this askubuntu stackexchange question about ASLR on details how to disable it.)
Update (Better Workaround)
I've looked into this a bit further, and while I still haven't found the root cause, I've found another workaround that doesn't require you to disable ASLR on your system.
What you can do is invoke the executable with the runtime linker directly, i.e. run
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 ./p 

(assuming you have x86_64, if you have a different architecture, check readelf -l executable and see what program it specifies for INTERP)
Background
When you run a program, the kernel checks the ELF header of the program for a so-called interpreter, also called the runtime dynamic linker, or ld.so. If that is present, it also loads that program into memory (in addition to the executable), and gives control to that program (instead of directly to the executable). The runtime dynamic linker is then responsible for actually loading all of the shared libraries the program is linked against. Once all shared libraries have been loaded, ld.so then invokes the startup routine of the program itself. (A statically linked program doesn't require an interpreter, and is executed directly by the kernel.)
But instead of letting the kernel load ld.so when your program is being started, you can also call ld.so directly and specify the program that is to be run as a command line argument to it. (That's a glibc feature.) This will cause ld.so to load the program itself (instead of relying on the kernel to have previously loaded it before loading ld.so), but after that it behaves like any other program.
This also makes sense of the fact why it only occurs with Ubuntu's own kernels, but not other kernels in Docker containers, and why the kernel is a factor w.r.t. ASLR here.

Wow, I don't know how you found that, but I am truly impressed. Thank you very much!

To be very clear: this is a workaround and not a solution. Disabling ASLR is not a good idea when it comes to security (because it is a very useful defense-in-depth strategy), but it can be acceptable to temporarily do so for development machines.

This is really interesting. I am planning to upgrade to Ubuntu 24.04 as soon as it is out (in a week or so), so we'll see if this reproduces in that environment as well. I think this bug is really important if it's something related either to the linux kernel or to ASAN libraries. This bug here in stackoverflow is not getting noticed, and i don't know who should I warn.

@Leandro I've done some additional tests, and I found that when combining glibc/gcc from either Ubuntu 22.04 or Debian 12 with either a vanilla kernel (from the kernel git sources) between 6.1 and current git master, as well as the Ubuntu kernels that come with 22.04, this error occurs. I couldn't reproduce it when using the kernels that come with Debian 12, neither in 12 itself, nor in backports. I've looked at the list of patches Debian applies to the kernel, and nothing in there looked even remotely relevant. I'm still looking into this further, but haven't found the root cause yet.

I investigated further, and tracked the change to a change in CONFIG_ARCH_MMAP_RND_BITS from 28 to 32. After then searching for that configuration option, I stumbled upon this question, which is the exact problem you had. Basically, it's a bug in libasan that was triggered by that kernel option change, which has been fixed in newer versions.

Alright, so maybe going forward to a new kernel will fix the issue (it's not clear at this point if Ubuntu 24.04 has 6.8 or 6.6). However, I currently have a kernel 6.5.0-27, no 6.6.x nor 6.7.x. Thank you very much for your time!

@Leandro No, it's not a new kernel. It's a different kernel option (available since 4.1) that caused this. You need a new version of libasan to fix this properly (you might want to ask Ubuntu to backport this commit to gcc). In the mean time you can use sudo sysctl -w vm.mmap_rnd_bits=28 to go back to the old kernel setting at runtime, which still keeps ASLR enabled, but without crashing older versions of libasan. Use /etc/sysctl.d to make that setting persistent across reboots.
